# JS event listeners stop working during item drag, only fire after pointerup and subsequent mousemove

Tags: javascript, event-handling, mouseevent

I am having trouble getting event listeners to fire when the actual event occurs. I have created a drag-and-drop system that sets a variable `hoveringOverTarget = true` on `pointerover` of the target, listens for `pointerdown` on an image, and then calls a function on `pointerup` to check if it's been released over the target.

```js
let hoveringOverTarget = false;
const target = document.querySelector('.dragtarget');
if(target) {
    target.addEventListener('pointerover', ()=>{
        hoveringOverTarget = true;
        console.log(hoveringOverTarget);
    });
    target.addEventListener('pointerleave', ()=>{
        hoveringOverTarget = false;
        console.log(hoveringOverTarget);
    });
}
function beginItemDrag(e) {
    console.log('beginItemDrag called');
    const item = e.target;
    if(target) {
        item.addEventListener('pointerup', ()=>{
            console.log('pointerup');
            releaseItem();
        });
    } else {
        console.log('No .dragtarget on page');
    }
}
function releaseItem(e) {
    const item = e.target;
    if(hoveringOverTarget) {
        console.log('YES!!!');
        readcard(item);
    }
}
document.querySelectorAll('.item').forEach(item=>item.addEventListener('pointerdown', beginItemDrag));
```

However, during dragging of the image, *no other event listeners respond*. The `pointerover` and `pointerleave` event listeners from lines 4 and 8 **no longer fire** when dragging the image in and out of the target zone (despite working fine when not dragging the image), and `pointerup` function does not fire on pointerup. Rather, nothing happens at all when I release the item, *unless* the mouse is then moved, even by one pixel, at which point the `pointerover` event finally fires (`hoveringOverTarget` is logged as true) and the `pointerup` event never fires at all.

Through various searching I have seen some people's problems solved by adding `e.preventDefault()` to event listeners. When I do this, neither event is ever fired at all.

What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nobody else was able to figure this one out, I'll post the changes I made that eventually worked.  I tried a whirlwind of different things, but I think my eventual success was mostly due to:

- attaching the `pointerup` event listener to the **entire document** rather than the individual item
- identifying the dragged item via a document-wide variable, so all functions can reliably access it (rather than hoping `e.target` was the right item when calling `releaseItem(e)` from a pointerup listener on an individual item)
- adding `e.preventDefault()` to `beginItemDrag()` which stops the browser's default image dragging behavior (different than standard element dragging behavior!!!) which selfishly blocks other event listeners during the course of its drag.

tl:dr; I hoisted variables out of the functions and made my event listeners more broad until finally I caught the right events.

```
let hoveringOverTarget = false;
let draggedItem = null;
const target = document.querySelector('.dragtarget');
if(target) {
    target.addEventListener('pointerover', ()=>{
        hoveringOverTarget = true;
        console.log(hoveringOverTarget);
    });
    target.addEventListener('pointerleave', ()=>{
        hoveringOverTarget = false;
        console.log(hoveringOverTarget);
    });
}
function beginItemDrag(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // this is CRUCIAL! Disables default image "draggable" functionality
    draggedItem = e.target;
    document.addEventListener('pointerup', releaseItem);
    if(target) target.style.boxShadow = '0 0 20px white, 0 0 40px white';
}
function releaseItem() {
    if(target) target.style.boxShadow = 'none';
    if(hoveringOverTarget) { readcard(draggedItem); }
    document.removeEventListener('pointerup', releaseItem);
}
document.querySelectorAll('.toolboxitem').forEach(item=>item.addEventListener('pointerdown', beginItemDrag));
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have found a successful work-around. Just in case anyone else comes here looking for answers, though, I suspect this was the source of the original problem: for touchscreen browsers that allow [direct manipulation](https://w3c.github.io/pointerevents/#dfn-direct-manipulation) (e.g., using a finger to pan or zoom the current page), `pointerdown` triggers [implicit pointer capture](https://w3c.github.io/pointerevents/#dfn-implicit-pointer-capture), which causes the target to capture all subsequent pointer events as if they were occurring over the capturing target. So `pointerleave`, e.g., will never fire. This continues until the capture is implicitly released after `pointerup`.

To fix the issue, you can just release the capture in your `pointerdown` event listener--here, `beginItemDrag`--if it has been set:

```js
if (e.target.hasPointerCapture(e.pointerId))
  e.target.releasePointerCapture(e.pointerId);
```